# Where is Break button in Dell Inspiron 15R

Tags: django, keyboard, webserver, break

I'm following instructions from

http://www.tangowithdjango.com/book/chapters/setup.html

On how to start a webserver.

```
$ python manage.py runserver

Validating models...

0 errors found
September 21, 2013 - 06:12:41
Django version 1.5.4, using settings 'tango_with_django_project.settings'
Development server is running at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
```

But To stop a webserver it says press CTRL-C

However when I am using Powershell, it says press CTRL-BREAK.

I cannot find the BREAK key anywhere, and I tried other CTRL-letter patterns to try and stop the webserver without closing the powershell terminal.

Any help?

Comment: You might want to run `cmd.exe` from powershell first so you can use Ctrl-C. See also [this question](https://superuser.com/q/550359/7216) in superuser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>FN</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd> however if it doesn’t work you may have to use an external USB keyboard for Pause/Break Function.

You may also use the Onscreen Keyboard.

Comment: @zeeshana elahi - you were the first to give hint to use onscreen keyboard, but CTRL-C works onscreen

Comment: Your comment will come handy. Thanks.

Comment: simple--> Ctrl + C is working for break .

Answer (score 11):

Try Fn-B. 
It works as a BREAK on my Inspiron 7559

Comment: I can confirm that "ctrl + fn + b" cancels builds in visual studio on my Latitude E5570.

Comment: FN+B = Break also work on my 2017 DELL INSPIRON 13 5000 series

Comment: Works on this Dell Precision 5501.

Answer (score 3):

Try using this CTRL + FN + S.

It works on Inspiron 15 5558.

Comment: Actually, it answers it. It somehow worked for me, too. I have Dell Inspiron 15 5000 and when I tried used some console-based program, I had to send a CTRL + Break and  .. found out there's no such key on the keyboard. Pressing CTRL+FN+S actually issued **some** signal that the program caught as a Control+Break. *Really*. I then checked with plain `ping -t 8.8.8.8` and again CTLR+FN+S was caught as if CTLR+Break. However, after some playing with keyboard and osk.exe, something switched and now CTLR+FN+S doesn't work, but instead, CTRL+FN+B works and issues 'control+break' signal. Weird. Works.

Answer (score 2):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> works on my inspiron 13 7000 Series

Answer (score 1):

According to the following image, there seem to be no <kbd>Pause</kbd> key in Inspiron 15R.

[image]

---

But, you can use [On Screen Keyboard (`osk`)](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/type-without-keyboard) if you are using Windows: Run `osk` and click `Ctrl` button, then click `Pause` button.

Comment: I don't find the Pause button on the on screen keyboard. I must have searched a million times!

Comment: I'm not sure if it's the keyboard chip, the windows keyboard driver, or just the console (cmd.exe) itself, but sometimes CTRL+FN+S or CTRL+FN+B is detected by console applications as Control+Break. I have no plugins/hacks/mods/etc which I'm aware that would add such functionality. Just Dell Inspiron 15 with no pause key and with windows 7.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have BREAK key on your keyboard in this case CTRL+C works just fine

Answer (score 1):

For HP Laptop keyboards use: Ctrl + Fn + Pause

Answer (score 0):

For Hp laptops, "Fn + right shift key" works as break key. So to exit you can press "ctrl + Fn + right shift key". But on pressing this combination it is coming out or the execution as well as power-shell. We need to find something which ends the execution of script but keeps power-shell running.

Answer (score 0):

When I performed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>Insert</kbd> on my Dell Latitude E7450 it immediately sent it to sleep. Still looking for solution that works --- Tried several of the above -- no idea if this is jacking things up or not w/ experimentation -- hopefully someone knows one that will work 100% on Dell Latitude. Bosses choice/not mine. =-)

Answer (score -1):

For Dell Laptop keyboards use:
Ctrl + Fn + Insert